# Changing the ripple color of a mat-input

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I've been struggling for a while now on how to manually change the ripple color of a `<mat-input>` element and I can't seem to get it to work in any way.

```
<input matInput
       type="number"
       (keydown)="updateManualPage(1)"
       placeholder="Filter"
       formControlName="filterParam1">
```

I've tried everything I could think of in the CSS, `.mat-form-field-underline`, `.mat-form-field-ripple`, including a giant block of classes I've shamelessly ripped out of another SO question/answer, using `::after` and `::before` selectors, trying to use `::ng-deep`, `!important` but nothing seems to change the color of the ripple from the blue one that is imported from `@import "../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";`

EDIT: Just read the API a bit better, so I found out that the border color that appears after the ripple is from the `<mat-form-field>` element, which has a color picker. However, that color picker can only have a value of 'primary', 'accent', and 'warn'. So now I'm wondering how it would be possible to insert a custom color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a alternative without using `::ng-deep` since it causes warnings during build.

css

```
.mat-form-field.mat-focused .mat-form-field-ripple {
  background-color: red !important;
}

.mat-form-field.mat-focused .mat-form-field-label {
  color: red !important;
}
```

or

```
.custom-ripple .mat-form-field.mat-focused .mat-form-field-label {
  color: red !important;
}

.custom-ripple .mat-form-field.mat-focused .mat-form-field-ripple {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

html

```
<div class="custom-ripple">
  <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Outline form field</mat-label>
    <mat-icon matSuffix>sentiment_very_satisfied</mat-icon>
    <input matInput placeholder="Favorite food" value="Sushi" />
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
<app-form-field></app-form-field>
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-input-a1mppn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fstyles.css,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fform-field%2Fform-field.component.ts)

Comment: Much better than using ::ng-deep, however in my specific case I have not been able to do it without, I've tried this on a few different projects and it worked perfect. Marked it as an answer since it avoids component styles bleeding

Comment: Regarding the use of ::ng-deep in order to prevent style bleeding, I presume it would be somewhat fine to use it with an ID selector? e.g. `::ng-deep #ID .mat-class... {}` and it would prevent the style for that .mat-class from bleeding? Since it's also ID selected.

Comment: @Baltr Yes, you can use it to restrict the flow of CSS, class/attribute can also be used in the same way

Answer (score 1):

Managed to figure it out, it was

```
::ng-deep .mdc-text-field--filled:not(.mdc-text-field--disabled) .mdc-line-ripple::after {
  border-bottom-color: *X* !important;
}
```